# Write predicate and write function (prolog/lisp)

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

Good afternoon guys i have a problem with a predicate, in Prolog, and a function in Lisp.

this is my json-write predicate

```
json_write(JSON, FileName) :-
   open(FileName, write, Stream),
   writeq(Stream, JSON),
   close(Stream).
```

i have also another predicate json_load

```
json_load(FileName, JSON) :-
   open(FileName, read, S),
   read_string(S, _, Str),
   close(S),
   json_parse(Str, JSON).
```

so the problem is that this example `json_write(json_obj([/* stuff */]), ’foo.json’),
json_load(’foo.json’, JSON).` does not work.

I know that it not working cause json_parse parse only object like this `{"nome":"Arthur","cognome":"Dent"}`

so if i call json-write predicate it create a file and the content has this format, for example, `json_obj([("nome", "Arthur"), ("cognome", "Dent")])`.

that is very different to `{"nome":"Arthur","cognome":"Dent"}` and json_parse fail.

The prof. says that the predicate isn't reversal.
He also says this 
`"No. We do not expect the json_write / 2 to convert the JSON object to a string and then print it. The thing is much simpler. The json_write / 2 takes a JSON object and prints it directly onto an output stream (*) descending recursively into its structure."`

Any ideas?

thanks guys

PS if we fix it i need some helps with lisp function that should be works at the same way

Comment: Are you asking how to write a recursive descent printing procedure? Have you tried google? I don't think it is significantly simpler to write directly to a stream than to create a string. And what about Lisp?

Comment: i don't know what is the best solution. i don't know if descent printing procedure is the only solution.

Comment: I'm asking for help to resolve this

Comment: Lisp tags removed. There is no Lisp content in the question.

Comment: The file content is `json_obj([("nome", "Arthur"), ("cognome", "Dent")])` because that's what you wrote to the file if you called, `json_write(json_obj([("nome", "Arthur"), ("cognome", "Dent")]), 'foo.json')`. Your `json_write/2` predicate is very generic. It simply writes whatever term you pass it to the file without regard to format. It looks like you're expected to write a predicate to parse `json_obj([("nome", "Arthur"), ("cognome", "Dent")])` and yield a JSON string, `{"nome":"Arthur","cognome":"Dent"}`. Did you write `json_parse`? If it fails, then that's where the problem may be.